# bibtex is producing a space before the period when printing references

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

For some of my references, a space is inserted before the final period when printing a reference.

Here is a minimal example:

[file mwe.tex]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
Example citation: \citet{stocks}

\bibliographystyle{kluwer}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

[file mybib.bib]

```
@article{stocks,
  title={{Household portfolios: An International Comparison}},
  author={Guiso, Luigi and Jappelli, Tullio and Haliassos, Michael},
  journal={Available at SSRN 245805},
  year={2000}
}
```

Here is the output I get. Note that the space is real, meaning I can select it:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you're getting a space after the `journal` field is that the `kluwer` bibliography style *requires* a `volume` field for entries of type `@article`. If there's no `volume` field, a space is inserted.

The bigger issue is that it's not right to use the `@article` entry type for a piece that doesn't appear to have been published as a journal article (with the journal featuring volume, number, and pages fields).

The `@misc` entry type seems more applicable for the entry at hand. Just change `@article` to `@misc` and `journal` to `howpublished` and recompile.

A separate comment: If you want to make it straightforward for your readers to track down a copy of this piece, it would be useful if you provided a tad more information than just "Available at SSRN 245805". E.g., the SSRN site itself suggests (`\url` wrapper added) the following piece of information:

```
howpublished = {Available at SSRN: \url{https://ssrn.com/abstract=245805}},
```

An MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{stocks,
  title={{Household portfolios: An International Comparison}},
  author={Guiso, Luigi and Jappelli, Tullio and Haliassos, Michael},
  howpublished = {Available at SSRN: \url{https://ssrn.com/abstract=245805}},
  year={2000}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib,har2nat}
\bibliographystyle{kluwer}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Example citation: \citet{stocks}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem with @book entries, where a space was inserted before the final period of a BibTeX entry. I realized that I included the <<Publisher>>:<<City>> information in the wrong field, leaving the actual publisher and city fields blank. Therefore a space was inserted.

Comment: @Dr.Beeblebrox - Thanks. Indeed, if one uses an unsuitable entry type or uses invalid fields, all kinds of weird things can occur.